# How to restore old content in a NSTextField?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to restore the old content of a NSTextField when the field has been edited and it is now empty.

I'm currently displaying a popup saying the field can't be empty. The method is triggered when the field looses focus:

```
- (IBAction)checkTitleField:(id)sender
{
    if ([[titleField stringValue] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSAlert * alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Title can't be empty"
                                          defaultButton:@"OK"
                                        alternateButton:nil
                                            otherButton:nil
                              informativeTextWithFormat:@"Please enter a title."];

        [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window
                          modalDelegate:self
                         didEndSelector:nil
                            contextInfo:nil]; 
        return;
    }
}
```

However I'm not able to restore the previous content of the field when the popup is dismissed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best thing is to use NSTextFormatter

Answer (score 1):

You can store the latest accepted value in an NSString variable upon view load (and whenever a new valid entry is made), and simply set the NSTextField text value back to this value whenever a blank entry is detected.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `UITextField placeholder property` in combination with VeryVito's suggestion. It will be displayed in the textfield whenever the textfield is empty. Also, I have found `if ([[titleField stringValue] isEqualToString:@""])` to be unreliable in detecting empty text fields. Please see this post for a solution: [How to test a UITextField for being nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672064/how-to-test-a-uitextfield-for-being-nil)